# Categorize Feeds with taxonomy terms automatically

Tags: 7, feeds

I want to fetch the content from various RSS sources into my site to display them in a section. I have installed the Feeds module and created the feed to fetch from, along with the Content Type that will host the fetched news, but I'd like to categorize them in order to display then in different groups using Views (i.e.: 'news', 'technology', 'sports', etc.).

Is there any way to tell the Feeds module to add a value to the generated node's "Category" field (whether this is a taxonomy term or text field)?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a term reference field to the feed node, you can map the value to the feed item node (inheriting values). The term can then be added when creating the feed node.